# Typescript errors don't match the definition file

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio-2015, definitelytyped

I just switched to VS2015 and Typescript 1.7 and get some weird type errors when using JQuery:

```
var someObj: <SomeCustomType> = <SomeCustomType>$element.data("source");
```

This line throws the following error:

> Type 'JQuery' is not assignable to type 'SomeCustomType'.

But the [JQuery definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L1553) shows (line 1553) that this function signature should return the `<any>` type:

```
interface JQuery {

    //...

    data(key: string): any;

    //...
}
```

The same code does not raise any error on VS2013 with the same Typescript version.

Edit: Of course, I could cast to `<SomeCustomType><any>`, but that would mean bloating the code with multiple casts that shouldn't have to be there, which is not satisfactory in this case where the `d.ts` file provides the right signature.

Is there something I'm missing ?

EDIT: Maybe my question was not clear.

In VS2013, using the same TS version and `d.ts` file,

```
$element.data("source")
```

everything is fine, VS2013 sees a `<any>` and is happy.

On the other hand, VS2015 thinks that the returned object should be a `JQuery`, and therefore complains, as if this definition file didn't expose the mentioned signature.

Comment: you could try casting what data returns to that type.

Comment: @toskv Of course, but that doesn't explain the root problem.

Comment: you can check the list of breaking changes here, maybe something comes up. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes

Comment: I don't know what version you are upgrading from but the explicit cast to the target type added in 1.6 seems like a good candidate. :)

Comment: @toskv No, the call signature explicitly returns <any>, but intellisense wants this return type to be of type <JQuery>. Explicitly casting doesn't change anything, as the cast object is still not assignable to SomeCustomType. I'm thinking of some intellisense mess up rather than a Typescript one, as VS2013 doesn't complain.

Comment: I would start debugging the compiler setup before the code.  Make sure it is in fact using the version of typescript you think, and that it is using the .d.ts that you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update to use the latest **jquery.d.ts** file as  TypeScript 1.7.5 is stricter and previous version of **jquery.d.ts** actually had a bug.

This is explained in [Relax index signature checks for type any](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4074)

You can use [TSD](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) for that by running

```
npm install tsd@next -g
tsd install jquery -ors
```

Comment: This is interesting, especially [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5969) linked from the one you provided. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it to the type you want:

```
var someObj: SomeCustomType = <SomeCustomType> $element.data("source");
```

Or shorter:

```
var someObj = <SomeCustomType> $element.data("source");
```

Comment: As already said, my intellisense won't let me do that, because it thinks that the function return type is `JQuery` and not any, when the def file says otherwise.

Comment: hm, then indeed it looks more like an intelisense issue. :(